# How to use variables for line selection in sed?

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I want to use variables to only do replacement in a particular part of the file using sed, like this:

```
sed -i.out "$OUT,$OUT2 s|AllowOverride None|AllowOverride All|g" /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

However, this returns the following error message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `,'
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like one or the other of `OUT` and `OUT2` is empty or contains unexpected whitespace.  The error message looks like `OUT` is the culprit, and is probably empty.

Comment: his $OUT is empty , I think

Comment: show `echo "$OUT,$OUT2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, my $OUT variable was indeed empty. When it contained a value, it worked.

Answer (score -4):

If you are trying to replace al occurrences of "AllowOverride None" for "AllowOverride All" you can do this way

sed -i 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: OP is trying to the changes between range of lines.

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: I am indeed trying to do the change between a range of lines.